# UIPageControl & NIB design changed from code is incorrect

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, nib, uipagecontrol

I have storyboard, that uses separate NIB file to load content of `UIScrollView`. Everything works fine.

I have put `UIScrollView` inside `UIPageControl`. Now, when I change "page", I need to programatically change (reposition, stretch) some elements. Problem is, if I do this, after page is fully loaded, my elements "jump" to location that was set in NIB and ignore changes I made in my code.

I have tried to put those changes in "will" and "did" kind of methods, but without luck. Once my view goes visible, it is in its default state, ignoring my changes. If I put button and do changes in button click response, elements are correcttly changed / repositioned / stretched. But that is obvisouly not what I want.

If I turn off Auto-layout, it is working. But that is kind of "ugly" solution.